# Laravel 5.6 not getting input value

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel is not getting the number value, i have the controller and route set up fine because i tested this out in tinker, and it works. However it looks like there is an issue on how the input is getting passed to the controller.

its not getting this `$request['val'];`

**Route**

`Route::post('rate/{book_id}','BookController@rate');`

**BookController.php**

```
public function rate(Request $request, $book_id)
{

    $book = Book::find($book_id);

    $rating = new willvincent\Rateable\Rating();
    $rating->rating =  $request['val'];
    $rating->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    $book->ratings()->save($rating);



}
```

**show.blade.php**

```
   <h5>Click to rate:</h5>

    <form action="{{ url('rate', ['book' => $book->id] ) }}" method="POST">
        <input name="val" value="0" type="number">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: try $request->book_id and also you need to change variable name book_id not book on "<form action="{{ url('rate', ['book' => $book->id] ) }}" method="POST">"

Comment: im trying to pass the input value to the controller getting the book id works fine.

Comment: why you pass book id in url ? why don't you take a hidden field in form named form_id?

Comment: that doesn't help me answer my question thank you though.

Comment: that didn't work though.

Comment: make sure you add proper namespace which is "use Illuminate\Http\Request;"

Comment: the way the request is set up is fine, i used the same logic $request[] on another controller method so its not the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you know that `$request` is an object of `Request` class.

You can't access the value by this system - `$request['val']`.

Object can be accessed by `->` like it will be,

```
$rating->rating =  $request->val;
```

What you are using [], by this system, we can extract data's from array.

**For More clearance,**

In `web.php` name the route like,

```
Route::post('rate/{book_id}','BookController@rate')->name('rate');
```

In view,

```
<form action="{{ route('rate', $book->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input name="val" value="0" type="number">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In Controller,

```
$rating->rating =  $request->val;
```

Comment: `$rating->rating =  $request->val;` didn't work though.

Comment: action="{{ url('rate', ['book' => $book->id] ) }}" will be action="{{ url('rate', $book->id ) }}" I hope then..

Comment: What you got then try dd()

Comment: i get The page has expired due to inactivity.

Comment: now im starting to see my problem thank you so much, but i still have to solve this clue. It got me closer

Comment: can you type hoot hoot ?